# Bash script to copy numbered files in reverse order

Tags: linux, bash, sequence, rename

I have a sequence of files:

```
image001.jpg
image002.jpg
image003.jpg
```

Can you help me with a `bash` script that copies the images in reverse order so that the final result is:

```
image001.jpg
image002.jpg
image003.jpg
image004.jpg  <-- copy of image003.jpg
image005.jpg  <-- copy of image002.jpg
image006.jpg  <-- copy of image001.jpg
```

The text in parentheses is not part of the file name.

Why do I need it? I am creating video from a sequence of images and would like the video to play "forwards" and then "backwards" (looping the resulting video).

Comment: Why not just feed the video creation tool the list of images forwards and then backwards?

Comment: Because I'm using several command line tools like gifsicle (to make gifs) and ffmpeg (to make mpg) and am working with a large number (100-200 images) that would probably exceed the length of an acceptable command. Or is there no such limit?

Comment: It depends on how your tool takes the filenames for input. Unfortunately it seems that ffmpeg doesn't have a way of taking a file containing a list of filenames as input.

Comment: Neither does gifsicle :-( But the script provided below works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I'd use an array for this... that way, you don't have to hard code a value for $MAX.

```
image=( image*.jpg )
MAX=${#image[*]}
for i in ${image[*]}
do
   num=${i:5:3} # grab the digits
   compliment=$(printf '%03d' $(echo $MAX-$num | bc))
   ln $i copy_of_image$compliment.jpg
done
```

I used 'bc' for arithmetic because bash interprets leading 0s as an indicator that the number is octal, and the parameter expansion in bash isn't powerful enough to strip them without jumping through hoops. I could have done that in sed, but as long as I was calling something outside of bash, it made just as much sense to do the arithmetic directly.

I suppose that Kuegelman's script could have done something like this:

```
MAX=(ls image*.jpg | wc -l)
```

That script has bigger problems though, because it's overwriting half of the images:

```
cp image001.jpg image006.jpg # wait wait!!! what happened to image006.jpg???
```

Also, once you get above 007, you run into the octal problem.

Comment: This fails if there is an illegal character in the file name, like an underscore. BC doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `printf` to print a number with leading 0s.

```
$ printf '%03d\n' 1
001
$ printf '%03d\n' 2
002
$ printf '%03d\n' 3
003
```

Throwing that into a for loop yields:

```
MAX=6

for ((i=1; i<=MAX; i++)); do
    cp $(printf 'image%03d.jpg' $i) $(printf 'image%03d.jpg' $((MAX-i+1)))
done
```

Comment: Nice script but it generates redundant copies. +1 anyway.

Comment: For the given case, it would be better to `ln` instead of `cp` the files.

Comment: Should it be `for ((i=1; i<=MAX/2; i++));` ? Or I guess the result is the same, so the simpler version is better

Comment: @glglgl, that's an interesting idea. Could you give the `ln` command? Would I make a symbolic link or a hard link?

Comment: Like above, but just ln instead of cp. If you want to make symbolic links (which is up to you), add -s. Both types of links can be used here.