# Create a new sequence of files from an existing sequence, along with numbering

Tags: bash, rename

I know this question has been asked, but I can't find more than one solution, and it does not work for me. Essentially, I'm looking for a bash script that will take a file list that looks like this:

image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg

And then make a copy of each one, but number it sequentially backwards. So, the sequence would have three new files created, being:

image4.jpg
image5.jpg
image6.jpg

And yet, image4.jpg would have been an untouched copy of image3.jpg, and image5.jpg an untouched copy of image2.jpg, and so on. I have already tried the solution outlined in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136222/bash-script-to-copy-numbered-files-in-reverse-order) with no luck. I am admittedly not very far down the bash scripting path, and if I take the chunk of code in the first listed answer and make a script, I always get "2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" over and over. I've tried changing the syntax with the ( around a bit, but no success ever. So, either I am doing something wrong or there's a better script around.

Sorry for not posting this earlier, but the code I'm using is:

```
image=( image*.jpg )  
MAX=${#image[*]}  
for i in ${image[*]}  
do  
   num=${i:5:3} # grab the digits  
   compliment=$(printf '%03d' $(echo $MAX-$num | bc))  
   ln $i copy_of_image$compliment.jpg  
done
```

And I'm taking this code and pasting it into a file with nano, and adding !#/bin/bash as the first line, then `chmod +x script` and executing in bash via `sh script`. Of course, in my test runs, I'm using files appropriately titled image1.jpg - but I was also wondering about a way to apply this script to a directory of jpegs, not necessarily titled image(integer).jpg - in my file keeping structure, most of these are a single word, followed by a number, then .jpg, and it would be nice to not have to rewrite the script for each use.

Comment: We cannot help with the syntax error if you don't post the code. Please do.

Comment: Thanks fir the update  The array syntax is a basism, make sure you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file, otherwise you might be ending up with `sh` (or even `csh`, on some platforms).

Comment: Upon closer reading, the error is `sh script`; you want `bash script` (or just `./script`) instead.

Comment: Hey @triplee, thanks much for the suggestion, but I'm still running into errors. If I try in an empty directory, after issuing `touch image1.jpg` (and again for 2 and 3) and then so `bash script`, I get an output of `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` on the first line, then `ln: creating hard link 'copy_of_image000.jpg': File exists` and those lines repeat, both with and without `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script. An `ls` will then show just the image(interger).jpg files and a singular `copy_of_image000.jpg`. Using `./` has the same results.

Comment: Looks like your index is not updating properly then.  I have not attempted to troubleshoot that part of the code.

Comment: @user unknown This is working pretty well, but I run into two issues: the first is that I need to rename any images in the directory to "image(integer).jpg" instead of, say "snapshot01.jpg". NBD tho. I ran the script and it worked if there were only a few images, but if I run it with images where the numbers span up to two digits (in this case, image00.jpg through image24.jpg), first I get `./script.sh: line 7: 2*26-08: value too great for base (error token is "08")`. Next, when I look at the directory, I see that only  image44.jpg through image51.jpg have been created.

Comment: @user1388721: Well, you have to tell us, what your real requirements are. So the Filename can be (alpha)(number).jpg - can it be (number)(alpha).jpg too? Can it be .png too? How shall we know? If your filenames are filled with leading zeros, by cutting them off, you get 001, 002, ... 007, 008, 009, 010, ... But leading zeros are often interpreted as octal numbers, and 8 and 9 aren't valid octal numbers. So you have to cut the number of, remove leading zeros, do arithmetic, and fill it up again. But in general, this isn't a `code me the solution, please`-platform, but help with problems. ...

Comment: So you should try to solve the problems on your own, show us what you did, what didn't work, what did you expect, what was the result instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.  It will work well for something like `script image*.jpg` where the wildcard matches a set of files which match a regular pattern with monotonously increasing numbers of the same length, and less ideally with a less regular subset of the files in the current directory.  It simply assumes that the last file's digit index plus one through the total number of file names is the range of digits to loop over.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Extract number from final file name
eval lastidx=\$$#
tmp=${lastidx#*[!0-9][0-9]}
lastidx=${lastidx#${lastidx%[0-9]$tmp}}
tmp=${lastidx%[0-9][!0-9]*}
lastidx=${lastidx%${lastidx#$tmp[0-9]}}

num=$(expr $lastidx + $#)
width=${#lastidx}

for f; do
    pref=${f%%[0-9]*}
    suff=${f##*[0-9]}
    # Maybe show a warning if pref, suff, or width changed since the previous file
    printf "cp '$f' '$pref%0${width}i$suff'\\n" $num
    num=$(expr $num - 1)
done |
sh
```

This is `sh`-compatible; the `expr` stuff and the substring extraction up front is ugly but Bourne-compatible.  If you are fine with the built-in arithmetic and string manipulation constructs of Bash, converting to that form should be trivial.

(To be explicit, `${var%foo}` returns the value of `$var` with `foo` trimmed off the end, and `${var#foo}` does similar trimming from the beginning of the value.  Regular shell wildcard matching operators are available in the expression for what to trim.  `${#var}` returns the length of the value of `$var`.)

Comment: This works perfectly. I would like to take this time to admit that as @userunknown mentioned, I am indeed not a very skilled coder, but am just a beginning beginner. I would like to apologize if I offended him in any way. I am just getting started in this and very much appreciate that anyone was willing to help, even if there was very little input from me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe your real test data runs from 001 to 300, but here you have image1 2 3, and therefore you extract one, not three digits from the filename. num=${i:5:1}
- Integer arithmetic can be done in the bash without calling bc
- ${#image[@]} is more robust than ${#image[*]}, but shouldn't be a difference here.
- I didn't consult a dictionary, but isn't compliment something for your girl friend? The opposite is complement, isn't it? :)
- the other command made links - to make copies, call cp.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
image=( image*.jpg )
MAX=${#image[@]}
for i in ${image[@]}
do
    num=${i:5:1}
    complement=$((2*$MAX-$num+1))
    cp $i image$complement.jpg
done
```

Most important: If it is bash, call it with bash. Best: do a shebang (as you did), make it executable and call it by ./name . Calling it with sh name will force the wrong interpreter. If you don't make it executable, call it bash name.

Comment: Why don't you accept an argument for the command line to say what files to process?  Maybe like `image=($1*${2-.jpg})`

Comment: @tripleee: Because the user copied some script from a foreign source, and didn't do anything to solve the problem himself. Did he present a plan, how to solve it? A step, where he had problems to progress? The script failed, because he took it from a page where the filename was bla001.jpg, not bla1.jpg . It linked the images, but didn't copy them. Do you have the impression that he noticed what these errors? That it is a coder? Or is this a "be my gratis coder" request?